# python : New to python tried to make a rock paper scissors game

Tags: python

i tried to make a rock paper scissors game but it doesn't work it just ask for user input and does nothing else.

```
import random

def main():
    user = input("Choose 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper or 's' for scissors ")
    comp = random.choice(['r','s','p'])
    if user == comp:
        return 'Tie'
    
    if win(user,comp):
        return 'Winner'
    else:
        return "Loser"
    
def win(o,p):
    if(o =='r' and p == 's' ) or (o =='p' and p == 'r' ) or (o =='s' and p == 'p' ):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    win()
```

Comment: it depends on what you intend for your code to do with x.

Comment: Do you actually call `game()` from anywhere? Otherwise all you did was define a function, that is not the same thing as executing that function.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help to see a [mcve] including how you are calling your function so that we can better understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given code you are returning some value, so here you need to store that value in some kind of variable as `main()` is running correctly and after execution it's returning `Tie, Winner, Loser`.
So need to print the result:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

or store the output in variable and print that variable.
And if you want to loop within main you can print value instead of return.

And no need to call `win()` I don't see any need for calling that below `main()`

Answer (score 0):

In the above given snippet, you are only defining the function, but not calling it. Try calling the function as shown below and you will be able to get the user input.

```
game()  #Calling the function
```

This results:

```
>> enter something
```